# wordpress mysql query for post thumbnail

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to make a query to get the post title, link and images of the post. I have what I need with the following query:

```
SELECT WPPOSTS.post_title,WPPOSTS.guid,WPPOSTS_2.image
FROM wp_posts WPPOSTS
LEFT JOIN
( 
SELECT guid AS image,post_parent
FROM  wp_posts
WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
ORDER BY post_date_gmt DESC
) WPPOSTS_2 ON (WPPOSTS_2.post_parent = WPPOSTS.ID)
WHERE WPPOSTS.ID IN (2439,2395,2355)
```

Now, what I really want is to get only the last thumbnail inserted in the post, not all of them. That's the reason why I have already considered the order by clause. I have tried putting a "LIMIT 1" inside the LEFT JOIN SELECT but I guess that's wrong.

Any idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to put a LIMIT on your nested select, because it will only find 1 row - not one row for each post like you intend.

You can use a nested select to find the MAX(post_date_gmt) for each post (I think you would want to GROUP BY post_parent?) and then select the guid for the image that matches the highest post date.

Try something like the following (I have not tested this, so take it with a grain of salt):

```
SELECT a.post_title,max(c.guid)
FROM wp_posts a

LEFT JOIN
(select post_parent, max(post_date_gmt) as latest_image_date from wp_posts
where post_type='attachment' GROUP BY post_parent) b 
on a.id=b.post_parent

LEFT JOIN wp_posts c
on c.post_parent=a.id 
and c.post_type='attachment' 
and b.latest_image_date = c.post_date_gmt

GROUP BY a.post_title
```

The final selection of MAX on the guid for each post was just an attempt to guarantee uniqueness in the unlikely event there are multiple images with the exact same timestamp on a single post.

Answer (score 4):

I post my solution as this might help others, too. Because the above code works but also prints NULL elements for max(c.guid), I filter those results. Beside this, it is easier to get the results if the associative array returned gets nice names:

```
SELECT a.post_title title, max(c.guid) img_url, a.ID id
FROM wp_posts a

LEFT JOIN
(select post_parent, max(post_date_gmt) as latest_image_date from wp_posts
where post_type='attachment' GROUP BY post_parent) b 
on a.id=b.post_parent

LEFT JOIN wp_posts c
on c.post_parent=a.id 
and c.post_type='attachment' 
and b.latest_image_date = c.post_date_gmt where c.guid IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY a.post_title ORDER BY a.ID
```

A mysql_fetch_array() might look like this:

```
title   img_url     id
Despre  http://localhost/drumliber/wp-content/uploads/2009...   2
Brandul de tara al Romaniei - imnul turistic    http://localhost/drumliber/wp-content/uploads/2009...   9
```